# Generate PDF in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

I got file response from API

[image]

I want to generate it as PDF and open using [open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex)

This is what I have tried

```
@override
  Future<Either<Failure, dynamic>> getInvoicePDF(GetInvoiceParams param) async {
    return await Factory().exceptionsGuard(() async {
      var res = await RemoteDataSourceResponseGuard.execute<dynamic>(
        _invoiceRemoteDataSource.downloadInvoicePDF(
            sessionToken: param.sessionToken,
            userId: param.userId,
            invoiceId: param.invoiceId),
      );

      await generatePDF(res);
    });
  }

  Future generatePDF(dynamic value) async {
    debugPrint("file response $value".toString());
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;

    File file = File('$dir/"file".pdf');

    await file.writeAsBytes(value);

    try {
      OpenFilex.open(file.path);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("error $e");
    }
  }
```

**InvoiceRemoteDataSource**

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart';

part 'invoice_remote_data_source.g.dart';

@RestApi()
abstract class InvoiceRemoteDataSource {
  factory InvoiceRemoteDataSource(
    Dio dio, {
    String baseUrl,
  }) = _InvoiceRemoteDataSource;

  @POST('/download_invoice_pdf')
  Future<dynamic> downloadInvoicePDF({
    @Field("session_token") required String sessionToken,
    @Field("user_id") required String userId,
    @Field("invoice_id") required String invoiceId,
  });
}
```

The value display in log is `%PDF-1.4`

Here the error

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'
```

This is the part of the response which shows in log.

[image]

Comment: It means your `value` is `String`, while `file.writeAsBytes` only accept bytes `List<int>`. 
What is the log value from  `debugPrint("file response $value".toString());` ?

Comment: @ductran `file response %PDF-1.4`

Comment: that means your download code is incorrect, please check it or show me the code

Comment: @ductran I have provided relevant code here.This is the part of the response which shows in log. 

```I/flutter (16068): %PDF-1.4
I/flutter (16068): 1 0 obj
I/flutter (16068): <<
I/flutter (16068): /Title (��
I/flutter (16068): /Creator (��
I/flutter (16068): /Producer (��
I/flutter (16068): /CreationDate (D:20230803153313Z)
I/flutter (16068): >>
I/flutter (16068): endobj
I/flutter (16068): 3 0 obj
I/flutter (16068): <<
I/flutter (16068): /Type /ExtGState
I/flutter (16068): /SA true
I/flutter (16068): /SM 0.02
I/flutter (16068): /ca 1.0
I/flutter (16068): /CA 1.0```

Comment: I mean the code to call api and receive the file, before you call `generatePDF()`
and what kinds of response type from api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to open it in this way.

```
Future<File> generatePDF(GetInvoiceParams param) async {
    var request = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse(
        "url"));
    var response = await request.close();
    var bytes = await consolidateHttpClientResponseBytes(response);
    String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    File file = File('$dir/pdfName.pdf');
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
    return file;
  }

 // then open the file path using openx
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to correct the retrofit response api to `HttpResponse<List<int>>` like this:

```
 @DioResponseType(ResponseType.stream)
 @POST('/download_invoice_pdf')
   Future<HttpResponse<List<int>>> downloadInvoicePDF({
   @Field("session_token") required String sessionToken,
  @Field("user_id") required String userId,
  @Field("invoice_id") required String invoiceId,
});
```

And here is the rewrite code to save the file:

```
  var res = await  RemoteDataSourceResponseGuard.execute<HttpResponse<List<int>>>(
    _invoiceRemoteDataSource.downloadInvoicePDF(
        sessionToken: param.sessionToken,
        userId: param.userId,
        invoiceId: param.invoiceId),
  );
  
  final bytes = res.data;
  await generatePDF(bytes);
```

Comment: got issue in my dio.g.dart https://imgur.com/OGNoPZP

Comment: try to add `@DioResponseType(ResponseType.stream)` just like my updated answer and try again

Comment: The type 'HttpResponse' is declared with 0 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given.
Try adjusting the number of type arguments to match the number of type parameters.

Comment: I updated my answer again.
Your issue is about downloading file, not saving. If you want to use retrofit, then try this way https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/issues/503#issuecomment-1427081797
After that you can get the bytes List<int> directly and just save to `file.writeAsBytes(bytes)`